# can an array take more elements than the indicated size in c

Tags: arrays, c

Here I have declared an integer array of `size 2` but I am able assign **more than 2** elements to the array and also print them but the array size is indicated as of `size 8bytes` before and also after assigning a value to it.

```
int main()
{
    int a[2];
    printf("size is %d\n",sizeof(a));
    a[0]=1;
    a[1]=2;
    a[2]=3;
    a[3]=4;
    a[4]=5;
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]);
    printf("size is %d\n",sizeof(a));
}
```

**Output**

```
size is 8
1 2 3 4
size is 8
```

So is it possible to assign more elements than the specified size to an array? If yes is it only applicable if you declare the array in this fashion and can this be applied to any type of array in c?

Comment: As you showed yourself it is possible but that leads to undefined behavior.:)

Comment: If you were expecting an error message when you tried this, your expectation was inaccurate.  You often don't get an error message, but that doesn't mean it's okay.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57247807/difference-in-storage-of-memory-in-string-and-an-integer-array-in-c-after-using/57252388#57252388), which is talking more specifically about strings, but the lessons are the same for any kind of array.