# Assigning value to an array of a length not initialized is not giving error or garbage value

Tags: c

I have declared the length of array as 4. But after assigning a[21]=56, is not giving me error. However, the output comes to be 56.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int a[4]={10,20,30,40};
a[20]=57;
printf("%d",a[20]); }
```

Comment: That is because accessing an array out of range is invoking **UB** (*Undefined Behavior*). It will never result in a compilation error. The fact that you actually get something is probably by pure luck.

Comment: What did you expect to happen?  If you expected an error message saying something like `array access out of bounds`, it turns out your expectation is quite incorrect for C.  If you expected something weird to happen, well: something weird *did* happen!

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57247807/difference-in-storage-of-memory-in-string-and-an-integer-array-in-c-after-using/57252388#57252388).

Comment: So it means we can assign value to an undefined length array?